# sbs 2008 exchange 2007 recipient filtering

Tags: exchange-2007, windows-sbs-2008, spam-filter

We have an SBS 2008 server with exchange 2007 installed on it. We run a spamfilter in front of it. My problem is that whenever I use an invalid email address. invalid@mydomain.com it gets accepted by the exchange even though the recipient filtering is enabled. The accepteddomain is mydomain and authoritative. I installed antispamagents-ps1 and restarted the services before that. I'm a bit new to this so if you could help me that would be really appreciated. Thanks.

RecipientValidationEnabled : True

[PS] get-transportagent

Identity                                           Enabled         Priority
--------                                           -------         --------
Transport Rule Agent                               True            1
Journaling Agent                                   True            2
AD RMS Prelicensing Agent                          False           3
Catchall Agent                                     True            4
Connection Filtering Agent                         True            5
Content Filter Agent                               True            6
Sender Id Agent                                    True            7
Sender Filter Agent                                True            8
Recipient Filter Agent                             True            9
Protocol Analysis Agent                            True            10

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Even though everything else was disabled in the transport agent, the priority still mattered. I set the recipient filter agent to priority 1 and it works fine. set-transportagent -identity "recipient filter agent" -priority 1 Telneting and trying an invalid address returns unknows user. However one could question how this works if the priority matters even though everything else is disabled. Thanks.